# postgresql - insert a row after trigger: Error: text search configuration name "myparser" must be schema-qualified?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a trigger on mytable:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_trigger 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(tsv, 'myparser', title);
```

But when I insert a row

```
insert into mytable (title) values ('great bulding')
```

There is an error:

> ERROR:  text search configuration name "myparser" must be schema-qualified;

There is List of text search configurations below:

```
           List of text search configurations
   Schema   |    Name    |              Description
------------+------------+---------------------------------------
...
pg_catalog | turkish    | configuration for turkish language
pg_catalog | myparser   |
public     | fulltest   |
(18 rows)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `tsvector_update_trigger` procedure?

Comment: this procedure is a postgresql internal procedure，I think the problem is 
associated with the trigger or "myparser"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I know, I must point the `schema` of test search configuration using `.` while creating a trigger.
so I should use

`CREATE TRIGGER mytable_trigger 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(tsv, 'pg_catalog.myparser', title);`

or `public.fulltest` or `pg_catalog.turkish`;